Straightening out a photo that was taken at an angle
Someone took a photo of a painting at an angle. I need to fix this.

I need to move the four corners of the painting to the respective four corners of the brown boundary around it.
How do I do this?

I find it much easier in Lightroom Classic, if you have that.  In the Develop module, open the Transform panel and click Guided.  Draw a line along each of the four sides by clicking one point and dragging to click another point.  It will make the four sides fit a rectangle.  Squares even come out squares.

You could use the perspective crop tool. To get to it, click and hold the crop tool, until you see the extra hidden tools appear in the little fly out menu, and select it.

With the tool selected click on each of the four corners of the painting, and hit Enter to accept the crop.

After the crop

If you think it looks a little squished, increase the canvas height, and select the image and stretch it a bit using the Transform tool Cmd/Ctrl+T

Finally use the regular crop tool to trim any uneven edges and any blank space


I don't see a Perspective Crop tool in Photoshop 2024 or in Photoshop 2025.  Where is it?

It is hidden behind the normal Crop tool. Press and hold the Crop tool and the Perspective Crop tool should be available. You can see the relevant icon in this documentation article: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/crop-straighten-photos.html

@PaulReiners Sorry, I've added a little screenshot to the answer showing the the tool location. To get to it, click and hold the crop tool, until you see the extra hidden tools appear in the little fly out menu, and select it.
